# If $p^2=a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta$ ,then show that $p+\frac{d^2p}{d\theta ^2}=\frac{a^2b^2}{p^3}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $p^2=a^2\cos^2\theta +b^2\sin^2\theta$ ,then show that $p+\frac{d^2p}{d\theta ^2}=\frac{a^2b^2}{p^3}$.I am struggling with this math.Any hints or solution will be appreciated.And i do apologize if this question is very basic.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: What is $y$ supposed to be?

Comment: sorry it's a type mistake :) @mrtaurho sir

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove $p^2+pp''=\frac{(ab)^2}{p^2}$. Since $p^2=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}+\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}\cos 2\theta$, $pp'=\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}\sin 2\theta$ and $pp''+p'^2=(b^2-a^2)\cos 2\theta$. Hence $$p^2+pp''=p^2-p'^2+(b^2-a^2)\cos 2\theta=p^2-\frac{(a^2-b^2)^2}{4}\frac{1-\cos^22\theta}{p^2}+(b^2-a^2)\cos 2\theta.$$The rest follows from writing $\cos 2\theta$ in terms of $p^2$.